# How to use the spare and wasted tooth brushes?

Tags: substitute-tool

Is there any tips to reuse the wasted tooth brushes in a useful and interesting way?

Comment: What do you mean by spare or wasted?  Surely you would just use a spare toothbrush as a toothbrush.   Or do you mean a used, worn-out toothbrush?

Comment: @Chenmunka yeah I mean used or worn-out toothbrush.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to lifehacks. Were you looking for specific instructions for something or a list of things a small brush can be used for which might be fun but is outside question topic guidelines in the Help Centre [?]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use old toothbrushes for cleaning multiple surfaces in multiple ways.

For grout: I drill a small hole in the center of the head, push a small bolt through, add nut, tighten, cut off the toothbrush handle and install it as a bit into my drill. Instant power 
scrubber. You can do the same with a larger [scrub brush](https://snapguide.com/guides/attach-a-scrub-brush-to-a-power-drill-for-the-ultimate-cleaning-hack/).

For cleaning small parts or jewelry: Apply appropriate cleaner to toothbrush and scrub away. Much easier cleaning tool than a sponge or scrub pad.

[image: toothbrush scrubber]

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](https://www.bikehacks.com/best-mountain-bike/), you can use toothbrushes to clean [bike chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_chain). I have to admit I never did this myself; I *have* used dish brushes for similar purposes.

[image]
<sub>(source: [bikehacks.com](https://www.bikehacks.com/.a/6a0120a7ed5f9d970b01b8d0c3a265970c-800wi))</sub>

Comment: As someone who does all his own bike maintenance, I can corroborate that a toothbrush is a hand tool for cleaning may parts.  I never thought to create my own chain cleaner using two.  Clever.

Comment: hehe bit ironic that you of all people didn't use imgur to upload images...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a toothbrush and elbow grease to clean all types of surfaces. Here are some other uses:

Toothbrushes are better at cleaning inside glasses (for drinking from) than the average dish brush because the dish brushes are too large to fit inside small glasses.  You can use toothbrushes to brush caked-on dirt and mud off of your shoes.

Untested uses:

You can try using a toothbrush to remove pilling from sweaters. You can try using it to apply facepaint or makeup at your own risk.

Comment: Our family likes to use old toothbrushes for cleaning grout. They can actually reach between tiles, unlike larger scrubbers that pass over top.

Comment: @pboss3010 Right, toothbrushes are great for scrubbing all kinds of surfaces. I didn't want to get into that though, because I thought it was common knowledge so not a lifehack.

Answer (score 2):

The uses of toothbrush is as follow:

1. To dye hair near forehead without smudging.
2. To clean stainless steal taps.
3. To remove dust from wooden furniture specialy from that areas where we can't reach or the design of furniture does not allow us to clean directly.
4. To remove dead skin cells from your lips.
5. For painting.

Answer (score 1):

I use worn-out toothbrushes for several purposes:

- to remove dirt under my fingernails,
- to clean files and sandpaper.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a toothbrush to clean out clogged shower drains. If the drains tend to get clogged with hair, it's convenient to use a toothbrush to clear it out (rather than using your hands/fingers directly).

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible uses for old toothbrushes:

1. Cleaning the Bathroom
2. Polishing Shoes
3. Cleaning the mold in a Washer
4. Cleaning the bottoms of shoes
5. Cleaning ovens

Answer (score 1):

Your question mentions "spare" toothbrushes, so I'll add this suggestion.  Toothbrush sanitizers are becoming increasingly popular, especially when in close proximity to a toilet (Google for details).  Rather than, buy another gizmo, I have 7 toothbrushes, one for each day of the week.  At end of the week I put them through the dishwasher.  Toothbrush sanitation solved!

[image: Toothbrush Sanitation]

Comment: Nevertheless the toothbrushes will be worn out after some time (albeit longer).

Answer (score 0):

One way an old toothbrush can be used is to clean air conditioner filters. Air conditioner filters need to be cleaned regularly and a toothbrush can be an effective way to do it.

One way to do it is described in an [article on Family Handyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/article/this-nifty-trick-will-clean-up-your-air-conditioner/):

> After removing the filter from your air conditioning unit, you are going to want to rinse it under warm water. This will help to get rid of the initial filth on the filter. Take a spray bottle and fill it with warm water and either some soap or dish detergent. Spray the grimy spots on your filter with the bottle, then use a toothbrush to scrub off the grime.